# Вывести все файлы, которые может исполнять ТОЛЬКО владелец

Tags: linux, bash

Не получается вывести файлы в папке, которые может исполнять только владелец, а так же файлы исполняемые. Как если файл может исполнять и владелец и группа посчитать только один раз?

```
    let q=0
    for i in *
    do
    if [ -x $i ]
    then
    let q=q+1
    fi
    done
    echo $q
```

другая попытка

```
    find $1  -type f -perm -u+rx | wc -l
```

Comment: Никогда не используйте _*_ в скрпитах на shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> вывести файлы в каталоге, которые может исполнять только владелец

```
$ find путь -maxdepth 1 -type f -perm /u=x -not -perm /go=x
```

- `-maxdepth 1 -type f` — ограничиться только файлами, расположенными непосредственно в указанном каталоге
- `-perm /u=x` — для владельца разрешено исполнение
- `-not` — отрицание последующей директивы
- `-perm /go=x` — для группы или остальных разрешено исполнение

> а так же файлы исполняемые

```
$ find путь -maxdepth 1 -perm /a=x
```

* `-perm /a=x` — для владельца или группы или остальных разрешено исполнение

или

```
$ find путь -maxdepth 1 -perm -a=x
```

* `-perm -a=x` — для владельца и группы и остальных разрешено исполнение

> Как если файл может исполнять и владелец и группа посчитать только один раз?

добавьте отрицание (`-not`) с нужной логикой.

разрешено исполнение для владельца:

```
-perm /u=x
```

разрешено исполнение для группы:

```
-perm /g=x
```

разрешено исполение для владельца, но не для группы:

```
-perm /u=x -not -perm /g=x
```

разрешено исполнение для группы, но не для владельца:

```
-perm /g=x -not -perm /u=x
```

и т.д. и т.п.

---

доп. чтение: [symbolic modes of file permissions](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Symbolic-Modes.html#Symbolic-Modes)